# Windows Azure CDN doesn't serve gzipped assets, even after uploading assets twice, one is gzipped and the other one is plain

Tags: azure-storage, cdn, azure-cdn

I have gone through a lot of questions on stackoverflow about windows azure CDN not being able to serve gzipped assets.I also had gone through certain links which say it could be done. I'm a li'l confused so thought of posting a question in here.

I have a rails app that serves all its assets from windows Azure CDN. Everything works fine but CDN fails to serve gzipped content. Here's a link [a link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/e2fac591-bba0-49e1-9adf-988525e22cbc/) thats suggests to upload the files twice one which is plain and the other one which is gzipped as a work-aroung to this problem. I followed the instructions but in vein. Here is what the link says:

```
    The feature in our backlog (as Jason Sherron points out) is the ability of the
    Windows Azure CDN to autonomously create a compressed version of your content to    serve 
    in response to a request for gzip encoding. Unless and until we get to implement that, 
    you'll have to upload content twice, once in each desire encoding.
```

The headers are all set fine and works amazing if I dont host on the CDN.
Does anyone have a work-around to this problem? Can this be done ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have a work around that helps but its a big and tedious process.
First I compress all my assets and remove the .gz extension from them then set their content-encoding header as gzip on azure. This gets me the required gzipped files but I guess thats not the best way :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Content-Encoding on the files to gzip

Also, this is an important gotcha, you can't serve the gzipped files with a .gz extension as Chrome and Firefox assume its a regular gzipped download file and do not decompress it.

So you need to change the extension e.g. .jsgzip for a script file rather than .js.gz

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I'm sure chrome and firefox do recognize .gz extensions and decompress them, as I had them stored with the same extension and they worked just fine. Anyway, will try it too.

Comment: I can't find the source code lines and more to demonstrate this issue in both chrome and firefox (had done previously) but there are two related bugs that demonstrate the issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=268085 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=610679